# MPEG4Writer.cpp, how is this related to MediaRecorder.setOrientationHint()?

Tags: java, android, c++

I am trying to connect the MPEG4Writer.cpp class with MediaRecorder's setOrientationHint(). It was mentioned that the two were related. From what I have seen of the MPEG4Writer.cpp,

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libstagefright/MPEG4Writer.cpp

This handles things like duration, encoding, decoding primarily. Can someone help me understand the connection to orientation? I found one method of interest that might be it because of the latitudex and logitudex values, I was curious if that would be the orientation equivalent.

```
MPEG4Writer::MPEG4Writer(int fd)
    : mFd(dup(fd)),
      mInitCheck(mFd < 0? NO_INIT: OK),
      mIsRealTimeRecording(true),
      mUse4ByteNalLength(true),
      mUse32BitOffset(true),
      mIsFileSizeLimitExplicitlyRequested(false),
      mPaused(false),
      mStarted(false),
      mWriterThreadStarted(false),
      mOffset(0),
      mMdatOffset(0),
      mEstimatedMoovBoxSize(0),
      mInterleaveDurationUs(1000000),
      mLatitudex10000(0),
      mLongitudex10000(0),
      mAreGeoTagsAvailable(false),
      mStartTimeOffsetMs(-1) {
}
```

Thanks in advance!